# Select2 multiple not working after partialview refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, partial-views

I am new to this select2 multiple,
I have a select2 multiple code for selecting multiple in my project as show below,

```
$('.itemName').select2({
    //data: data,
    placeholder: 'Select a Language',
    ajax: {
        url: '/User/LanguageSelect/',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

this is in the partrial view, it works fine in the fisrt time but when partial view get refreshed i can not type anything in the box,

i tried adding this line of code too..

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('.itemName').select2();
});
```

But when i added this the select2 is not working in the first place either, what did i do wrong??

this is the view i get one first load

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJNbW.png)

and after partialview load i get like this

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpwRr.png)

please help

Comment: What error message do you get? and what does your selector look like?

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft there is no error showing, and i updated the question with images. i can only add links now

Comment: How do  you render the partial view? show us that code.

Comment: sorry i used the jquery in the view where partial view is loaded, now i added the code in partial view and it works fine :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your partial view is loaded (there could be an event for that) you must (re-)bind all your jQuery objects.

You're on the right track as far as I can see, but the first select2 instantiation is different and besides that I suspect that you're not hooked onto the right event (`ajaxComplete`).

Can you share how you load your PartialView?

If you don't know any of this; just add this to your PartialView:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.itemName').select2({
            // add stuff
        });
    });
</script>
```